# How to implement a take_until_and_consume-like parser combinator that does not skip the tag?

Tags: rust, nom

I would like to write a nom parser combinator that takes as many bytes up to and including a tag sequence. I tried using `take_until_and_consume!`, but I found that the generated parser combinator discards the tag sequence:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

named!(up_to_and_including_backslash, take_until_and_consume!("\\"));

fn main() {
    let res = up_to_and_including_backslash(b"    \\");
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

Results in:

```
Done([], [32, 32, 32, 32])
```

What I would like is for the tag sequence (in this case, the backslash character) to be included in the result:

```
Done([], [32, 32, 32, 32, 92])
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**update:**
You want to use `recognize!` on `take_until_and_consume!("\\")` to add everything it consumed to the Output.

You would write your parser function like this:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

named!(up_to_and_including_backslash, recognize!( take_until_and_consume!("\\") ));

fn main() {
    let res = up_to_and_including_backslash(b"    \\");
    println!("{:?}", res);
}
```

In case you needed to include the consumed symbols of multiple parsers to your Output you could put them all inside a `do_parse!` within `recognize!`. Like so:

```
recognize!( do_parse!( tag!("\\") >> take_until_and_consume!("\\") >> take!(4) >> () ) )
```

**old:**
<s>The only way I got this to work was this ugly abomination.</s>

```
named!(up_to_and_including_backslash,
    do_parse!(
        line: take_until_and_consume!("\\") >>
        (
            { 
                let mut complete_line:Vec<u8> = line.to_vec();
                complete_line.extend_from_slice(b"\\");
                &*complete_line
            }
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Right now you are using the method `take_until_and_consume` whose Documentation says:

> generates a parser consuming bytes until the specified byte sequence
>   is found, and consumes it

The consume part is important, since it is what you want to avoid.

You could do something akin to this:

```
named!(up_to_and_including_backslash,
    do_parse!(
        line: take_until!("\\") >> char!('\\') >>
        (line)
    )
);
```

Which should return the line with your seperator.

Comment: I tried out your proposed solution, but the result is still `Done([], [32, 32, 32, 32])`.